# How can I detect whether bubbling encounters a certain type of element?

Tags: javascript

I have several div elements with a canvas in each of them:

I decided to add a listener to the div with ID everything. How can I detect whether a click on that div is also a click on a div with class dog?

I tried

```
document.getElementById('everything').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.debug(e.target);
});
```

but `console.debug(e.target);` only gives me the canvas that was clicked on.

I could just simply assign an event listener to the dog div, but I don't want to do that since I might have lots of children divs inside of the div IDed with 'everything'.

Comment: Can you provide Relative `HTML` I mean `#dog` is inside (child) of `#everything` or is a parent of it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this is jQuery But try this.

and It's hardly possible to make sure if `#everything` is a parent of `.dog` or not though

The case "#everything" is parent of ".dog", this should work.

```
$("#everything").on("click",function(e){
  if $(this).closest(".dog").length > 0
    console.log("element covering both #everything and .dog has clicked")
  else
    console.log("#everything has clicked but not .dog")
})
```

hope This would help.